# LibGDX smooth admob interstitial between screens

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob

I am looking to implement admob interstitals between screens in my libGDX game. I am loading the ad when the MainMenuScreen class is called(every four times) I have it working except every time I show the ad my game screen and main menu screen jitter/jump between each other for a second or two before the ad is shown, resulting in a very bad transition. If anyone could help me achieve a smoother showing of the ad, that'd be great.

Android AndroidLauncher class

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver {

    //Code omitted 

public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
    j++;
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded() && (i<12) && (j%4==0)) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    i++;
                }
                else if (!interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

LibGDX GameScreen class

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    //Code omitted      
    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

            //Code omitted 
            dispose();
            game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
    }
}
```

LIBGDX MainMenuScreen class

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    //Code omitted      
        @Override
    public void show() {
        game.actionResolver.showOrLoadInterstital();
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the dispose() method? Shouldn't that go in your screens dispose method? You must have MainMenuScreen setting the screen back to GameScreen if they are going back and forth...can't tell from the code here though.